# Performing arbitrary arithmetic operations that a user provides to the system using stack (stack implementation being done with linked lists)

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

I'm using the following code to perform stack implementation in the case of solving arbitrary arithmetic operations:

```
def precedence(op):
    if op == '+' or op == '-':
        return 1
    if op == '*' or op == '/':
        return 2
    return 0



def operation(a, b, op):
    if op == '+': return a + b
    if op == '-': return a - b
    if op == '*': return a * b
    if op == '/': return a / b

def evaluate(tokens):
    # This is a stack to store integer values
    values = []

    # This stack stores operators
    ops = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(tokens):


        if tokens[i] == ' ':
            i += 1
            continue


        elif tokens[i] == '(':
            ops.append(tokens[i])


        elif tokens[i].isdigit():
            val = 0


            while (i < len(tokens) and
                   tokens[i].isdigit()):
                val = (val * 10) + int(tokens[i])
                i += 1
            values.append(val)
            i -= 1


        elif tokens[i] == ')':

            while len(ops) != 0 and ops[-1] != '(':
                val2 = values.pop()
                val1 = values.pop()
                op = ops.pop()

                values.append(operation(val1, val2, op))
            ops.pop()


        else:
            while (len(ops) != 0 and
                   precedence(ops[-1]) >=
                   precedence(tokens[i])):
                val2 = values.pop()
                val1 = values.pop()
                op = ops.pop()

                values.append(operation(val1, val2, op))
            ops.append(tokens[i])
        i += 1


    while len(ops) != 0:
        val2 = values.pop()
        val1 = values.pop()
        op = ops.pop()
        values.append(operation(val1, val2, op))


    return values[-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ask = input('Enter your expression here: ')
    print(f"\nThe answer is {evaluate(ask)}")
```

But I have no clue how to translate this implementation of stack using linked list.

Can anyone help me? Or provide me with links that would be helpful in explaining stack using linked lists ?

Thanks!

Comment: the indentation of the code is all wrong.  i tried to edit it, but there are too many lines of code.   please copy and paste correctly.

Comment: Fix indentation

Comment: Indentation fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LLstack:

     def __init__(self):
         self.numNodes = 0
         self.tail = None
    
    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = self.numNodes
        self.index = self.tail
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if (self.n == self.numNodes):
            self.n-=1
            return self.index.val
        if self.n>0:
            self.n-=1
            self.index = self.index.next
            return self.index.val
        else:
            raise StopIteration
    
    def push(self,val):
        self.numNodes+=1
        if (self.tail!=None):
            temp = self.Node(val)
            temp.next = self.tail
            self.tail = temp
        else:
            self.tail = self.Node(val)
        
    def pop(self):
        if (self.numNodes==0):
            return None
        self.numNodes-=1
        val = self.tail.val
        self.tail = self.tail.next
        return val

    def size(self):
        return self.numNodes


    class Node: 
        def __init__(self,val):
            self.val = val
            self.next = None


if __name__== "__main__":
     stack = LLstack()
     for i in range(100):
         stack.push(LLstack())
     i = iter(stack)
     for x in i:
         print(x)
```

https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.